# Attach Event Listener to MotionAnimation in UWP

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

I have setup a MotionAnimation in this way:

```
public static void StartSpringAnim(this Panel view)
{
    Visual viewVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(view);
    SpringScalarNaturalMotionAnimation springAnimation = viewVisual.Compositor.CreateSpringScalarAnimation();
    springAnimation.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
    springAnimation.DampingRatio = 0.5f;
    springAnimation.StopBehavior = AnimationStopBehavior.SetToFinalValue;
    springAnimation.InitialValue = (float) view.Margin.Left;
    springAnimation.FinalValue = (float)view.Margin.Left + 50;
    viewVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.X", springAnimation);
}
```

I would like to attach an event handler to the animation, so that I get notified once the animation is done (so that I can perform some further operations).

How can I achieve such result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track composition animations using `CompositionScopedBatch`

```
    public static void StartSpringAnim(this Panel view)
    {
        Visual viewVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(view);
        SpringScalarNaturalMotionAnimation springAnimation = viewVisual.Compositor.CreateSpringScalarAnimation();
        springAnimation.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
        springAnimation.DampingRatio = 0.5f;
        springAnimation.StopBehavior = AnimationStopBehavior.SetToFinalValue;
        springAnimation.InitialValue = (float)view.Margin.Left;
        springAnimation.FinalValue = (float)view.Margin.Left + 50;

        var scopedBatch = viewVisual.Compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation);
        scopedBatch.Completed += Animation_Completed;
        viewVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.X", springAnimation);
        scopedBatch.End();
    }

    private void Animation_Completed(object sender, CompositionBatchCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        //this will fire on animation complete
    }
```

more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionscopedbatch